# Group row data in a 2d array by 3 column values and sum "h:m" formatted values in another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have a multidimensional array in the form of;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Bob Hope
            [ITEM] => Holiday
            [DURATION] => 04:00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Bob Hope
            [ITEM] => Work
            [DURATION] => 05:00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Bob Hope
            [ITEM] => Holiday
            [DURATION] => 06:00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Bob Hope
            [ITEM] => Work
            [DURATION] => 05:00
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Joe Bloggs
            [ITEM] => Holiday
            [DURATION] => 02:00
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Joe Bloggs
            [ITEM] => Work
            [DURATION] => 03:00
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Joe Bloggs
            [ITEM] => Holiday
            [DURATION] => 03:00
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Joe Bloggs
            [ITEM] => Work
            [DURATION] => 02:00
        )
)
```

And want to collate the results, totalling the holiday and work for each person so that I can output something in the form of;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Bob Hope
            [ITEM] => Holiday
            [DURATION] => 10:00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Bob Hope
            [ITEM] => Work
            [DURATION] => 10:00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Joe Bloggs
            [ITEM] => Holiday
            [DURATION] => 05:00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [DATE] => 05-19-2011
            [PERSON] => Joe Bloggs
            [ITEM] => Work
            [DURATION] => 05:00
        )
)
```

Any ideas? Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: he's grouping them e.g. Holiday for Bob Hope was combined and has DURATION of 10 on the second example.

Comment: @Ghommey [DURATION] is sum'ed and there is unique entry's for [ITEM] over [NAME]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a lot of foreach's, but you are basically adding the values in a separate structure, and rearrange the resulting array:

```
$items = array(
    0 => Array(
        'DATE' => '05-19-2011',
        'PERSON' => 'Bob Hope',
        'ITEM' => 'Holiday',
        'DURATION' => '10:00',
    ),
    1 => Array(
            'DATE' => '05-19-2011',
            'PERSON' => 'Bob Hope',
            'ITEM' => 'Work',
            'DURATION' => '10:00',
    ),
    2 => Array(
            'DATE' => '05-19-2011',
            'PERSON' => 'Joe Bloggs',
            'ITEM' => 'Holiday',
            'DURATION' => '05:00',
    ),
    3 => Array(
            'DATE' => '05-19-2011',
            'PERSON' => 'Joe Bloggs',
            'ITEM' => 'Work',
            'DURATION' => '05:00',
    ),
);

foreach($items as $key=>$value){
    $item = $value['ITEM'];
    $out[$value['PERSON']][$value['DATE']][$value['ITEM']] += $value['DURATION'];
}

foreach($out as $person=>$data){
    foreach($data as $date=>$items){
        foreach($items as $item=>$duration){
            $result[] = array(
                'PERSON'=>$person,
                'DATE'=>$date,
                'ITEM'=>$item,
                'DURATION'=>$duration,
            );
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Where's the data coming from? Generally, such data comes from a database, in which case the following statement would do exactly what you want:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(DURATION),
   ITEM,
   PERSON
FROM
   yourtable
GROUP BY 
   PERSON, 
   ITEM;
```

Edit: If you want to group them by items too, just declare that.

Comment: I would normally agree with you but this is a simplified version of my problem. My problem is to do with the grouping and aggregation of values. But as what you have said is correct I have voted the answer up.

Comment: Thanks. Well, if it *is* coming from the database, chances are you can do whatever you want more simply with SQL than with PHP.

Comment: in this case i too would recommend using SQL, because things will get very ugly in php, not only because you would also have to parse the duration to seconds for summing them up. if you use mysql, there is a function for this btw.: TIME_TO_SEC('00:00:00') and you can sum it up as berry showed. i am sure you can format the duration for TIME_TO_SEC much more easy than building a solution for this in php.

Answer (score 0):

- Declare a new array.
- Iterate over the old array
- If the new array is empty, add the current array element to it
- If not, iterate over the new array

  - if none of the new array's elements match the current array element, add it
  - else add the current element's DURATION to the relevant new array's element

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to solve this with PHP i would recommend to not nest too many loops. Here is my solution (which looks quite ugly btw.):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $key = $row['PERSON'] . '|' . $row['ITEM'];
    $tmp = explode(':', $row['DURATION']);
    $row['DURATION'] = $tmp[0] * 60 + $tmp[1];

    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$key]['DURATION'] += $row['DURATION'];
    }
}

$result = array_map(function($v) {
    $v['DURATION'] = strftime('%M:%S', $v['DURATION']);

    return $v;
}, array_values($result));
```